# Timer vs. repetitive background worker

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, wcf, timer

I am developing a Windows Forms application that calls a WCF service after a specified interval and shows output according to the data received from the service. I had a plan to use timer for this purpose that calls that WCF service method after 500 msec. But some of my colleagues told me to use background worker and then on `Work_Completed`event re-run the Worker. I want to know what is the difference between these two? Does timer also creates a background thread? Which one is best suited for long running tasks?

Comment: What Timer? There are multiple. Some use threads some don't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `Timer` is almost certainly more suitable in terms of resource consumption.  A `BackgroundWorker` is going to create a new thread just for that task.  Creating a new thread is a fairly expensive operation.  While there are many different timer implementations, and their implementations will vary, they are generally going to be reliant on OS tools that will fire an event periodically, which is going to be preferable to starting up a new dedicated thread.

Most of the key differences in `Timer` objects is what they do when they're "ready".  Some create a new thread pool thread; some have a dedicated thread that is shared by all instances of the timer to run the handler(s), some marshal the code to the UI thread (or some other synchronization context) and it's the latter that you probably want.  If you use the timer that is made available in the particular UI framework that you're using it's the behavior that you'll see.

Answer (score 6):

[From MSDN website](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fed51ca1-8ade-4826-9b3d-24c1a913dae5/backgroundworker-vs-timer?forum=netfxbcl) :-

> BackgroundWorker creates a thread on the ThreadPool (via asynchronous
>   delegate invoke). The BCL timers use either a ThreadPool thread to
>   raise the event, or in some cases will raise the tick/elapsed/etc
>   events on the UI thread (in the case of a WinForms timer or a
>   Timers.Timer that has an ISynchronizeInvoke supplied to it).
>
> The BackgroundWorker provides an optimal API for background threads in
>   a UI environment. It allows for a method to run on the background
>   thread (via the DoWork event) and provides a simple way to be notified
>   of progress and completion on the UI thread (ProgressChanged and
>   RunWorkerCOmpleted events) without having to worry about any
>   cross-thread invocation.
>
> The WinForms timer executes on the UI thread and is safe to touch any
>   UI element from its elapsed event. However, you are not guaranteed to
>   execute at exact intervals, it's all dependnet on what's going on on
>   the UI thread. Let me repeat one important thing: there is no
>   background thread with this option!
>
> Threading.Timer is kind of an "ugly API" timer. Timers.Timer simply
>   wraps Threading.Timer into a nicer API and provides a way to
>   automatically invoke the elapsed event on the UI thread (via the
>   SynchronizingObject property). If you set the SynchronizingObject
>   property, no code executes on a background thread, it gets immediately
>   marshalled to the UI thread.
>
> In general, inside a UI, the BackgroundWorker is simply easier to deal
>   with than the other choices.

Comment: So this means at deeper system level, a standard timer is just a recursive function?

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva No.  What makes you say that?

Comment: @Servy as I just read in above answer that timer executes on UI thread, so under my knowledge I think it should be a recursive function. Because its a part of the UI thread(UI class) and it freezes UI when it executes. I am just asking not sure about that. Actually I want to know what is timer actually at deeper level? I saw MSDN explanations but they are just for development purposes. I actually want to know this for my self knowledge and research.

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva It doesn't need to be recursive to marshal the event invocation to the UI thread; it just needs to call the appropriate method of the synchronization object to add the event handler to the message queue.  There's nothing recursive about that.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, the main benefit [Background Worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.aspx) is that the `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted` events will execute on the same thread that the worker was instantiated on. So, if you start your background worker on your UI thread, the RunWorkerCompleted event will also fire on the UI thread. That makes it so you don't have to worry about making illegal cross-thread calls if you want to update your UI components when your background work completes.

Comment: There are (serveral) `Timer` classes that you can use that will also tick in the UI thread; you don't need a BGW to get that behavior.

Comment: I thought the only one that ticked in the UI thread by default was the System.Windows.Forms.Timer. There's a good article comparing the timers here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx

Comment: The `System.Timers.Timer` can be configured to fire in the UI thread, and you need to consider all of the timers specific to each UI paradigm.  There's the forms timer, and the WPF timer (DispaterTimer), etc.

Answer (score 3):

A standard `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` should be fine.  It calls its callback on the UI thread which means that while you are processing inside the callback it will potentially freeze your UI responsiveness.  But that's only an issue if you do a lot of work inside the callback or if you block the thread.

To avoid blocking the thread, just execute an asynchronous WCF call.

A `BackgroundWorker` makes no sense for what you want to do.  All you want to do is to wait 500ms before executing some code so just use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.